# Pandas dataframe select rows with multiple columns' string conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a similar dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'year':2017, 'text':'yes it is', 'label_one':'POSITIVE', 'label_two':'positive'}, 
{'year':2017, 'text':'it could be', 'label_one':'POSITIVE', 'label_two':'negative'},
{'year':2017, 'text':'it may be', 'label_one':'NEGATIVE', 'label_two':'positive'},
{'year':2018, 'text':'it has to be done', 'label_one':'POSITIVE', 'label_two':'positive'},
{'year':2018, 'text':'no', 'label_one':'NEGATIVE', 'label_two':'negative'},
{'year':2019, 'text':'you should be afraid of it', 'label_one':'POSITIVE', 'label_two':'negative'},
{'year':2019, 'text':'he is right', 'label_one':'POSITIVE', 'label_two':'positive'},
{'year':2020, 'text':'do not mind, I wil fix it', 'label_one':'NEGATIVE', 'label_two':'positive'},
{'year':2020, 'text':'that is a trap', 'label_one':'NEGATIVE', 'label_two':'negative'},
{'year':2021, 'text':'I am on my way', 'label_one':'POSITIVE', 'label_two':'positive'}])
```

How can I filter it in order to have just rows for which `label_one` and `label_two` string values are both `POSITIVE/positive` or `NEGATIVE/negative`

I tried with the following but it does not work:

```
ptp = df.loc[(df['label_one'].str.startswith('P') and df['label_two'].str.startswith('p')) & (df['label_one'].str.startswith('N') and df['label_two'].str.startswith('n'))]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works.  Following your pattern both start with P/p or N/n

```
ptp = df.loc[((df['label_one'].str.startswith('P')) &
              (df['label_two'].str.startswith('p'))) |          
             ((df['label_one'].str.startswith('N')) &        
              (df['label_two'].str.startswith('n')))]
```

gives

```
PTP
        year    text                label_one   label_two
    0   2017    yes it is           POSITIVE    positive
    3   2018    it has to be done   POSITIVE    positive
    4   2018    no                  NEGATIVE    negative
    6   2019    he is right         POSITIVE    positive
    8   2020    that is a trap      NEGATIVE    negative
    9   2021    I am on my way      POSITIVE    positive
```

Answer (score 4):

What about

```
df[df['label_one'].str.lower() == df['label_two'].str.lower()]
```

assuming that `label_one` and `label_two` only holds `negative`, `positive`, `NEGATIVE` or `POSITIVE`.